# how to plot a range with a line in the center with Plotly, in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe with a timestamp, and 3 columns: price, min and max

Here's a ghetto drawing I made of what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

I'd like to draw the min and max lines and then fill a zone in between them and then draw the price line in the middle.

How can this be done with Plotly? (I'm just switching from the little I knew on Matplot lib to the nothing I know about Plotly :))

Comment: Kindly refer to [this](https://plotly.com/python/continuous-error-bars/).

Comment: @vestland: yes, excellent, thanks! we can mark mine as a duplicate

Comment: @Thomas Give my suggestion a try. If it solves your problem, an upvote would be highly appreciated. If it doesn't, then edit THIS question with sample data and I'll take a closer look at your exact case in here.

Comment: @vestland, that's exactly what I needed! upvoted! also r-beginners, the link you sent is helpful as well; thanks!